# Using Scope And Relationship Within Same Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am having a really hard time trying to use the Scope and the Relationship elements of Eloquent within the same query.

My `201502_postcode` table has a column `gor` which has a foreign key lookup in the `pc_gor_030315` table. I ultimately want to return/display the `description` column within `pc_gor_030315` table.

I am using Scope, because my table names are likely to change. Don't worry about that here. I already have the code to do that. For simplicity I have called the tables `201502_postcode` and `pc_gor_030315`.

At the moment I am getting the following error;

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lookupTable()
```

Here is my controller;

```
$list = PostcodeExtract::fromTable('201502_postcode')
                        ->lookupTable('pc_gor_030315')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->select('description')
                        ->get();

var_dump($list);
```

Here is my `PostcodeExtract` model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class PostcodeExtract extends Model {

   protected $connection = 'postcodes';

    public function scopeFromTable($query, $tableName) 
    {
     return $query->from($tableName);
    }

    public function gorLookup()
    {
     //'oldcode' is the local key
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\GorLookup', 'oldcode'); 
    }
  }
```

And here is my GorLookup;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class GorLookup extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'postcodes';

    protected $fillable = array('description', 'oldcode');

    public function postcodeExtract()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostcodeExtract', 'oldcode');
    }

    public function scopeLookupTable($query, $lookupTable) 
    {
      return $query->join($lookupTable);
     }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your first scope.

`fromTable` scope is found in Eloquent Class `PostcodeExtract`.

Therefore, `PostcodeExtract::fromTable('201502_postcode')` works perfectly.

As for your second scope `lookupTable`, it is found in Eloquent Class `GorLookup`.

Therefore, it should be called with `GorLookup::lookupTable`.

However, in your code, you are chaining the scope `lookupTable` on an object of class `PostcodeExtract`, so it definitely won't work.

**Solution:**

Place the `lookupTable` scope in the `PostcodeExtract` class itself.